# Replication of the current Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Temp_Identity` with a single `IDENTITY` column.

When we are doing the replication, data from this table is correctly replicated. But its current identity is not replicated.

This means, the current identity of that table in the production database is 10. But in the replication database, it is still 1.

Is there any method to solve this automatically without doing manually?

Table Structure

```
 CREATE TABLE Temp_Identity
(
ID Int IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key,
Name Varchar(100)
)
```

When I insert the following  values in Production DB ,It is correctly effected inn Replication DB

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Identity
SELECT 'AA'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'CC'
```

When i Insert the given row from the Replication DB,I got a error.

```
 INSERT INTO Temp_Identity
  SELECT 'DD'
```

It is because,In the Replication DB,the table contains that three rows,When we do the above insertion,the value for the ID  column is '1' (Current Identity of that table in Production DB is 3.But in the Replication DB is 1. It should be same as that of Production DB). It is already exists in table.So the Primary Key error raised.

Comment: Generally you should not worry about the actual numbers in an identity column.  Just let the database handle this for you.

Comment: But when i try to insert a row into this table from this replication DB.A primary key error is raised. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: how can it be done?

Comment: Please show some example data which explains your problem.  Most likely, there isn't a real problem here.

Comment: You can disable primary constraints for the target table, and ID producing mechanisms just before insertion process start( Maybe you have a default sequence, or insert trigger which produces sequential numbers ).

Comment: It is not possible..we are running from our application. So we can't change our front end code...@BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Explanation added to the question..Pls have a look...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/replicate-identity-columns?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Probably this approach may work in this scenario.

```
create table tmptbl  (ID int identity(1,1) Primary key clustered, name varchar(100)) 
insert into tmptbl   
Select 'A' union all 
Select 'B' union all
Select 'C'
```

Create back up table

```
create table tmptbl_BCK  (ID int identity(1,1) Primary key clustered, name varchar(100)) 
insert into tmptbl_BCK   
select name  from tmptbl
delete from  tmptbl_BCK --to create the scenario this will remove the previous identity keys and create new keys for new insert. 

 insert into tmptbl_BCK 
 select name  from tmptbl 

select * from tmptbl (in original table) 
ID  name
1   A
2   B
3   C

select * from tmptbl_BCK  
ID  name
10  A
11  B
12  C
```

You can take help of Set Identity Insert option to make sure you have same identity in these tables. First make sure to delete the rows.

```
delete from  tmptbl_BCK
set identity_insert tmptbl_BCK On 
insert into tmptbl_BCK (ID, Name) select ID, name from tmptbl 
set identity_insert tmptbl_BCK Off 
select * from tmptbl_BCK

Output you get: 
ID  name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

Now if you want to have same identity value (in your replication table)  as production then you do in this way.

```
 Declare @reseedvalue int = (Select IDENT_CURRENT('tmptbl')) --though it gives you the last inserted value, next time it reseeds it will be 4 in your production table and replication table 
--select @reseedvalue

--to reseed based on your production table 
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('tmptbl_BCK', RESEED, @reseedvalue)

--test if it creates 4 in your back up table 
insert into tmptbl_BCK  
             select 'D' 
select * from tmptbl_BCK
```